# How can the information encoded in a boundary be changed in holographic principle?

Tags: string-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle, duality

When information is encoded in a lower dimensional boundary of a bulk, following the holographic principle, it would raise a universe in the boundary with physics determined by the information encoded on it.

My question is: **Can this information (once encoded in the boundary) be modified or changed? Can it be modified without changing nothing in the bulk?**

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand the holographic principle. It's wrong to think about it as if some dynamical boundary and some dynamical bulk separately existed and were correlated in some way (as happens with actual holograms) Instead this dynamical boundary and dynamical bulk are *the same thing* from two different mutually exclusive points of view. The same degrees of freedom can be thought as living on the boundary or reinterpreted as living in the bulk.

So all (physical) changes in the boundary description necessarily correspond to some changes in the bulk description.

Comment: thank you for your answer. So if we want to change the physics of the universe of the boundary we would have to change the boundary AND the bulk? I talked with a user in this site who told me that if we changed only the boundary we would be changing the physical quantity of the system we're studying. I suppose from your answer that this is not the same as changing the physics of the universe inside that boundary right? @OON

Comment: @user187597 Sorry for the late answer. The basic statement of the AdS/CFT is that you take certain observation and you may look at it as a process in CFT or you may look at it as a process in AdS. However there are certain nice properties of CFT that relate the states of the system with the operators i.e. basically various physical quantities you can measure. From that a somewhat more useful dictionary arises from the practical point of view. I suppose that the user you've talked with had in mind that dictionary. And the main idea of my answer is that there's no "AND". Rather "boundary = bulk"